# AWS Lambda function failing to access MySQL Database from an EC2 Instance : SequelizeConnectionError connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I am trying to access the MySQL database installed in an EC2 instance. I have written a simple AWS Lambda function in express js. The lambda function needs to access the MySQL. I am getting the below everyone when it is trying to establish the DB connection on EC2:

```
{
    "errorType": "SequelizeConnectionError",
    "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
    "name": "SequelizeConnectionError",
    "parent": {
        "errorType": "Error",
        "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
        "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
        "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "fatal": true,
        "stack": [
            "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT",
            "    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:173:17)",
            "    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)",
            "    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)",
            "    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)",
            "    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)"
        ]
    },
    "original": {
        "errorType": "Error",
        "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
        "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
        "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "fatal": true,
        "stack": [
            "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT",
            "    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:173:17)",
            "    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)",
            "    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)",
            "    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)",
            "    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)"
        ]
    },
    "stack": [
        "SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT",
        "    at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:149:19)",
        "    at tryCatcher (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)",
        "    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)",
        "    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)",
        "    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)",
        "    at Promise._settlePromises (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)",
        "    at Async._drainQueue (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)",
        "    at Async._drainQueues (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)",
        "    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)",
        "    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)",
        "    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)",
        "    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)"
    ]
}
```

**The ec2 configurations are:-**

[image: EC2 Instance configuration]

**Inbound Rules:**
[image: Inbound rules]

**Outbound Rules**
[image: Outbound Rules*]

**Lambda function**
[image: Lambda management console]

***NOTE: vpc, subnet, and security group are same in EC2 and lambda***

**Here is my code:-
[Lambda Function Code](https://repl.it/repls/CadetblueFrillyOctal)**

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: currently, can you access using ssh to ec2 instance ?

Comment: Yes I can access it using SSH

Comment: that mean ec2 instance go to the internet via internet GW not via NAT Gateway

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect from `lambda` function to ec2 instance.

Firstly, `Ec2 instances` and lambda function are being in the same VPC, and

Secondly, you have to create `NAT gateway` for lambda function. And subnet of EC2 instance and subnet of lambda function should be routed via the same `NAT gateway`.

For example :

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am following the first point. Let me try the second point. Can you please direct me to some article?

Comment: this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: Do I still need to setup NAT Gateway for RDS also?

Comment: Add RDS into subnet which route via NAT